# Cannot override default Material UI Icon styling

Tags: material-ui

I have an `AccountCircleIcon` Material UI icon and I want to increase the size, I've tried several things:

```
import AccountCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/styles';

const StyledIcon = withStyles({
  root: {
    fontSize: '50rem',
  },
})(AccountCircleIcon);

const login = () => {
  return (
    <div><StyledIcon /></div>
  );
};
```

```
import AccountCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    fontSize: '50rem',
  },
});

const login = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div><AccountCircleIcon classes={{root: classes.root}} /></div>
  );
};
```

```
import AccountCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  avatarIcon: {
    fontSize: '50rem',
  },
});

const login = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div><AccountCircleIcon className={classes.avatarIcon} /></div>
  );
};
```

But each time the default icon styling overrides the added styling:

[image]

Comment: It works using version `4.12.3`. Which version of `material-ui` are you using?

Comment: Just recreated the issue in a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-dewdney-1t832?file=/package.json which works, but on newer versions it doesnt. and it seems an version issue. Going to report it on their Github, perhaps I'm using the wrong packages together.

Comment: Your sandbox works just fine.

Comment: @Hamidreza sorry, i meant that on those versions it works, but if you upgrade the packages to the next versions the styling starts to break.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the `StyledEngineProvider` https://mui.com/guides/interoperability/ wrapping that around your app assures the custom css is injected first:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

export default function GlobalCssPriority() {
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      {/* Your component tree. Now you can override MUI's styles. */}
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-alex-nyszr?file=/src/Demo.tsx